# RactiveUI-Xamforms for PCL Profile259

Tags: windows, xamarin.forms, universal, reactiveui

Is **reactiveui-xamforms** available for windows universal project PCL (Profile259)? I am getting the following error when I tried to install the nuget package.

***Could not install package 'reactiveui-xamforms 6.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259, but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.***

My PCL is targeted to the following frameworks.Let me know if anything needs to be changed on this.

`.NET Framework 4.5
Windows 8
Windows Phone Silverlight 8
ASP.NET Core 5.0
Windows Phone 8.1
Xamarin.Android
Xamarin.iOS
Xamarin.iOS (Classic)`

Thanks,
RJ

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem recently, only my PCL targets profile 111. What I ended up doing was adding `reactiveui-xamforms` to `packages.config` manually. Now the RxUI-related part looks like that:

```
<package id="reactiveui" version="6.5.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
<package id="reactiveui-core" version="6.5.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
<package id="reactiveui-xamforms" version="6.5.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
```

After that, I restored nuget packages and referenced the downloaded dlls (also by hand, right-click on references node). And it works, as it turns out.

Hope this workaround works for you as well. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what actually causes the problem in the first place...

Comment: Thanks pmbanka...I removed Windows Phone 8.1 from the target list and I am able to install the package now. also this is compatible with windows 10 universal.. so I think I am good now.